# How do I remove a dispatchEvent's mouseOver?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```js
    document.addEventListener('focusin', function() { // this is so menu appears when user is navigating by tab
      if (document.activeElement.className.toString().includes("root-icon-yahome")) {
        item = document.activeElement
        document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { 'bubbles': true }));
      }
    }, true);
```

I want to remove the `mouseover` when user presses <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Not sure how to go about this.

Thank you

Comment: If you're using React there are probably better ways of achieving what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

```
item.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseout', { 'bubbles': true }));
```